# Processing large blocklists with GNU Parallel

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, perl, gnu-parallel

This is an ongoing project that has undergone a major update to speed up list processing. Here is the [homepage](https://github.com/T145/black-mirror/) for anyone interested!

It processes lists defined in `lists.json` by transforming the list content into raw hosts, and places those hosts into a lists that matches its corresponding action method and host format. The constants at the top of `build_lists.bash` show definitions for each of those variables.

Any advice on how make things faster or fix mistakes is welcome! It's also recommended to run the project in [this Docker environment](https://github.com/T145/black-mirror/pkgs/container/black-mirror). Just place all the files given here in the same directory and run `./build_lists.bash` after giving all the scripts run permissions. Also it's recommended to change the useragent in `aria2.conf`.

**Inputs:**

- [lists.json](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/T145/black-mirror/4968f8cd6d09e63f017994db24541202c1a39f81/data/v2/lists.json)
- [aria2.conf](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/T145/black-mirror/master/configs/aria2.conf)

**Scripts:**

**`build_lists.bash`**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#shopt -s extdebug     # or --debugging
set +H +o history     # disable history features (helps avoid errors from "!" in strings)
shopt -u cmdhist      # would be enabled and have no effect otherwise
shopt -s execfail     # ensure interactive and non-interactive runtime are similar
shopt -s extglob      # enable extended pattern matching (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html)
set -euET -o pipefail # put bash into strict mode & have it give descriptive errors
umask 055             # change all generated file perms from 755 to 700

DOWNLOADS=$(mktemp -d)
TMP=$(mktemp -p "$DOWNLOADS")
METHOD_ALLOW='ALLOW'
METHOD_BLOCK='BLOCK'
FORMAT_DOMAIN='DOMAIN'
FORMAT_CIDR4='CIDR4'
FORMAT_CIDR6='CIDR6'
FORMAT_IPV4='IPV4'
FORMAT_IPV6='IPV6'
readonly DOWNLOADS TMP METHOD_ALLOW METHOD_BLOCK FORMAT_DOMAIN FORMAT_CIDR4 FORMAT_CIDR6 FORMAT_IPV4 FORMAT_IPV6

METHODS=("$METHOD_BLOCK" "$METHOD_ALLOW")
FORMATS=("$FORMAT_DOMAIN" "$FORMAT_IPV4" "$FORMAT_IPV6" "$FORMAT_CIDR4" "$FORMAT_CIDR6")
readonly -a METHODS
readonly -a FORMATS

# https://github.com/ildar-shaimordanov/perl-utils#sponge
sponge() {
    perl -ne '
    push @lines, $_;
    END {
        open(OUT, ">$file")
        or die "sponge: cannot open $file: $!\n";
        print OUT @lines;
        close(OUT);
    }
    ' -s -- -file="$1"
}

sorted() {
    parsort -bfiu -S 100% -T "$DOWNLOADS" "$1" | sponge "$1"
    echo "[INFO] Optimized: ${1}"
}

# params: blacklist, whitelist
apply_whitelist() {
    # https://askubuntu.com/a/562352
    # send each line into the temp file as it's processed instead of keeping it in memory
    parallel --pipe -k -j+0 grep --line-buffered -Fxvf "$2" - <"$1" >>"$TMP"
    cp "$TMP" "$1"
    : >"$TMP"
    echo "[INFO] Applied whitelist to: ${1}"
}

# params: ip list, cidr whitelist
apply_cidr_whitelist() {
    if test -f "$1"; then
        sem -j+0 grepcidr -vf "$2" <"$1" | sponge "$1"
        sem --wait
        echo "[INFO] Applied CIDR whitelist to: ${1}"
    fi
}

init() {
    trap 'rm -rf "$DOWNLOADS"' EXIT || exit 1
    mkdir -p build/
    : >logs/aria2.log
    chmod -t /tmp
}

cleanup() {
    chmod +t /tmp
}

main() {
    local cache
    local list
    local blacklist
    local results

    init

    for method in "${METHODS[@]}"; do
        cache="${DOWNLOADS}/${method}"

        echo "[INFO] Processing method: ${method}"

        set +e # temporarily disable strict fail, in case downloads fail
        jq -r --arg method "$method" 'to_entries[] |
            select(.value.content.retriever == "ARIA2" and .value.method == $method) |
            {key, mirrors: .value.mirrors} |
            (.mirrors | join("\t")), " out=\(.key)"' lists.json |
            aria2c -i- -d "$cache" --conf-path='./aria2.conf'
        set -e

        echo "[INFO] Downloaded ${method} lists!"

        for format in "${FORMATS[@]}"; do
            results="${cache}/${format}"
            mkdir -p "$results"

            echo "[INFO] Sending list results to: ${results}"

            find -P -O3 "$cache" -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 |
                # https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#controlling-the-execution
                parallel -0 --use-cpus-instead-of-cores --jobs 0 --results "$results" -X ./apply_filters.bash {} "$method" "$format"

            list="build/${method}_${format}.txt"

            echo "[INFO] Processed: ${list}"

            find -P -O3 "$results" -type f -name stdout -exec cat -s {} + | sponge "$list"

            if [ -f "$list" ] && [ -s "$list" ]; then
                sorted "$list"

                if [[ "$method" == "$METHOD_ALLOW" ]]; then
                    blacklist="build/BLOCK_${format}.txt"
                    echo "[INFO] Applying whitelist: ${list}"

                    case "$format" in
                    "$FORMAT_CIDR4")
                        apply_cidr_whitelist "$blacklist" "$list"
                        apply_cidr_whitelist "build/BLOCK_IPV4.txt" "$list"
                        ;;
                    "$FORMAT_CIDR6")
                        apply_cidr_whitelist "$blacklist" "$list"
                        apply_cidr_whitelist "build/BLOCK_IPV6.txt" "$list"
                        ;;
                    *)
                        apply_whitelist "$blacklist" "$list"
                        ;;
                    esac
                else
                    # Remove IPs from the IP blacklists that are covered by the CIDR blacklists
                    case "$format" in
                    "$FORMAT_CIDR4")
                        apply_cidr_whitelist "build/BLOCK_IPV4.txt" "$list"
                        ;;
                    "$FORMAT_CIDR6")
                        apply_cidr_whitelist "build/BLOCK_IPV6.txt" "$list"
                        ;;
                    *) ;;
                    esac
                fi

                echo "[INFO] Processed ${method} ${format} list!"
            fi
        done
    done

    # https://superuser.com/questions/191889/how-can-i-list-only-non-empty-files-using-ls
    find -P -O3 ./build/ -size 0 -type f -name "*.txt" -exec rm {} \; # remove any empty lists
    find -P -O3 ./build/ -type f -name "*.txt" -exec sha256sum {} \; | sponge './build/CHECKSUMS.txt'

    cleanup
}

# https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2218
main
```

**`apply_filters.bash`**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

get_ipv4s() {
    ipinfo grepip -4hox --nocolor
}

get_ipv6s() {
    ipinfo grepip -6hox --nocolor
}

get_domains_from_urls() {
    perl -MData::Validate::Domain=is_domain -MRegexp::Common=URI -nE 'while (/$RE{URI}{HTTP}{-scheme => "https?|udp"}{-keep}/g) {say $3 if is_domain($3, { domain_private_tld => { onion => 1 } })}' 2>/dev/null
}

get_ipv4s_from_urls() {
    perl -MData::Validate::IP=is_ipv4 -MRegexp::Common=URI -nE 'while (/$RE{URI}{HTTP}{-scheme => "https?|udp"}{-keep}/g) {say $3 if is_ipv4($3)}' 2>/dev/null
}

hostsblock() {
    gawk 'BEGIN{FS="[|^]"}/^\|\|([[:alnum:]_-]{1,63}\.)+[[:alpha:]]+\^(\$third-party)?$/{print tolower($3)}'
}

# params: column number
mlr_cut_col() {
    mlr --csv --skip-comments -N clean-whitespace then cut -f "$1"
}

process_list() {
    local FILE_PATH
    local LIST_METHOD
    local CONTENT_FILTER
    local CONTENT_TYPE
    local LIST_FILTER
    local LIST_FORMAT

    FILE_PATH="$1"
    LIST_METHOD="$2"
    CONTENT_FILTER="$3"
    CONTENT_TYPE="$4"
    LIST_FILTER="$5"
    LIST_FORMAT="$6"

    case "$CONTENT_FILTER" in
    'NONE') cat -s "$FILE_PATH" ;;
    '7Z') 7za -y -so e "$FILE_PATH" ;;
    'ZIP') zcat "$FILE_PATH" ;;
    'GZIP') gzip -cd "$FILE_PATH" ;;
    'TARBALL') tar -xOzf "$FILE_PATH" ;;
    'SQUIDGUARD') tar -xOzf "$FILE_PATH" --wildcards-match-slash --wildcards '*/domains' ;;
    'SCAFROGLIA') unzip -p "$FILE_PATH" blocklists-master/*.txt ;;
    'SHADOWWHISPERER') unzip -p "$FILE_PATH" BlockLists-master/RAW/* ;;
    'ESOX_LUCIUS') unzip -p "$FILE_PATH" PiHoleblocklists-main/* -x PiHoleblocklists-main/LICENSE PiHoleblocklists-main/README.md ;;
    esac |
        case "$CONTENT_TYPE" in
        'TEXT')
            case "$LIST_FILTER" in
            'NONE') cat -s ;;
            'RAW_HOSTS_WITH_COMMENTS') mawk '/^[^[:space:]|^#|^!|^;|^$|^:]/{print $1}' ;;
            'HOSTS_FILE') ghosts -m /dev/stdin -o -p -noheader -stats=false ;;
            'ABUSE_CH_URLHAUS_DOMAIN') get_domains_from_urls ;;
            'ABUSE_CH_URLHAUS_IPV4') get_ipv4s_from_urls ;;
            'ALIENVAULT') mawk -F# '{print $1}' ;;
            'ADBLOCK') hostsblock ;;
            'GREP_IPV4') get_ipv4s ;;
            'GREP_IPV6') get_ipv6s ;;
            'BOTVIRJ_IPV4') mawk -F'|' '{print $1}' ;;
            'CRYPTOLAEMUS_DOMAIN') hxextract code /dev/stdin | head -n -1 | tail -n +6 ;;
            'CRYPTOLAEMUS_IPV4') hxextract code /dev/stdin | head -n -1 | tail -n +6 | get_ipv4s ;;
            'CYBERCRIME_DOMAIN') mawk -F/ '{print $1}' ;;
            'CYBERCRIME_IPV4') mawk -F/ '{split($1,a,":");print a[1]}' | get_ipv4s ;;
            'DATAPLANE_IPV4') mawk -F'|' '$0~/^[^#]/{gsub(/ /,""); print $3}' ;;
            'DSHIELD') mlr --tsv --skip-comments -N put '$cidr = $1 . "/" . $3' then cut -f cidr ;;
            'MYIP_DOMAIN') mawk -F, '$0~/^[^#]/{print $2}' ;;
            'MYIP_IPV4') mawk '$0~/^[^#]/{print $1}' | get_ipv4s ;;
            'MYIP_IPV6') mawk '$0~/^[^#]/{print $1}' | get_ipv6s ;;
            'VXVAULT_DOMAIN') mawk '/^[http]/' | get_domains_from_urls ;;
            'VXVAULT_IPV4') mawk '/^[http]/' | get_ipv4s_from_urls ;;
            'XFILES') tr -d "[:blank:]" | hostsblock | mawk '{print $2}' ;;
            'TRACKERSLIST') mawk '{print $1}' | get_domains_from_urls ;;
            'CHARLES_B_HALEY') mawk '$0~/^[^#]/{print $3}' ;;
            'QUANTUMULTX') mawk -F, '$1~/^HOST-SUFFIX$/{print $2}' ;;
            'QUINDECIM') mawk -F= '$0~/^=/{print $2}' | mawk '{print $1}' ;;
            'ZEEK_DOMAIN') mawk '/^[^[:space:]|^#]/&&$2~/^Intel::DOMAIN$/{print $1}' ;;
            'ZEEK_IPV4') mawk '/^[^[:space:]|^#]/&&$2~/^Intel::ADDR$/{print $1}' ;;
            esac
            ;;
        'JSON')
            case "$LIST_FILTER" in
            'ABUSE_CH_FEODOTRACKER_IPV4') jq -r '.[].ip_address' ;;
            'ABUSE_CH_FEODOTRACKER_DOMAIN') jq -r '.[] | select(.hostname != null) | .hostname' ;;
            'ABUSE_CH_THREATFOX_IPV4') jq -r 'to_entries[].value[].ioc_value | split(":")[0]' ;;
            'ABUSE_CH_THREATFOX_DOMAIN') jq -r 'to_entries[].value[].ioc_value' ;;
            'AYASHIGE') jq -r '.[].fqdn' ;;
            'CYBER_CURE_IPV4') jq -r '.data.ip[]' ;;
            'CYBERSAIYAN_DOMAIN') jq -r '.[] | select(.value.type == "URL") | .indicator' | get_domains_from_urls ;;
            'CYBERSAIYAN_IPV4') jq -r '.[] | select(.value.type == "URL") | .indicator' | get_ipv4s_from_urls ;;
            'DISCONNECTME_ENTITIES') jq -r '.entities[] | "\(.properties[])\n\(.resources[])"' ;;
            'DISCONNECTME_SERVICES') jq -r '.categories[] | to_entries[].value[] | to_entries[].value[]' ;;
            'HIPO_UNIVERSITIES') jq -r '.[].domains | join("\n")' ;;
            'ISCSANS') jq -r '.[].ipv4' ;;
            'MALSILO_DOMAIN') jq -r '.data[].network_traffic | select(.dns != null) | .dns[]' ;;
            'MALSILO_IPV4') jq -r '.data[].network_traffic | select(.tcp != null) | .tcp[] | split(":")[0]' ;;
            'MALTRAIL') jq -r '.[].ip' ;;
            'TINYCHECK_DOMAIN') jq -r '.iocs[] | select(.type == "domain") | .value' ;;
            'TINYCHECK_FREEDNS') jq -r '.iocs[] | select(.type == "freedns") | .value' ;;
            'TINYCHECK_IPV4') jq -r '.iocs[] | select(.type == "ip4addr") | .value' ;;
            'TINYCHECK_CIDR') jq -r '.iocs[] | select(.type == "cidr") | .value' ;;
            'CHONG_LUA_DAO_DOMAIN') jq -r '.[].url' | get_domains_from_urls ;;
            'CHONG_LUA_DAO_IPV4') jq -r '.[].url' | get_ipv4s_from_urls ;;
            'INQUEST_DOMAIN') jq -r '.data[] | select(.artifact_type == "domain") | .artifact' ;;
            'INQUEST_IPV4') jq -r '.data[] | select(.artifact_type == "ipaddress") | .artifact' ;;
            'CERTEGO') jq -rs '.[].links[].url' | mawk -F/ '$5~/^domain$/{print $6}' ;;
            'SECUREDROP') jq -r '.[] | .onion_address as $onion | .organization_url | split("/")[2] as $org | $org, $onion' ;;
            esac
            ;;
        'CSV')
            case "$LIST_FILTER" in
            'MLR_CUT_1') mlr_cut_col 1 ;;
            'MLR_CUT_2') mlr_cut_col 2 ;;
            'MLR_CUT_3') mlr_cut_col 3 ;;
            'MLR_CUT_4') mlr_cut_col 4 ;;
            'BENKOW_DOMAIN') mlr --csv --headerless-csv-output --ifs ';' cut -f url | get_domains_from_urls ;;
            'BENKOW_IPV4') mlr --csv --headerless-csv-output --ifs ';' cut -f url | get_ipv4s_from_urls ;;
            'BOTVIRJ_COVID') mawk 'NR>1' ;;
            'CYBER_CURE_DOMAIN_URL') tr ',' '\n' | get_domains_from_urls ;;
            'MALWARE_DISCOVERER_DOMAIN') mlr --csv --headerless-csv-output cut -f domain ;;
            'MALWARE_DISCOVERER_IPV4') mlr --csv --headerless-csv-output cut -f ip ;;
            'PHISHSTATS_DOMAIN') mlr_cut_col 3 | get_domains_from_urls ;;
            'PHISHSTATS_IPV4') mlr_cut_col 4 | get_ipv4s ;;
            'PHISHSTATS_IPV6') mlr_cut_col 4 | get_ipv6s ;;
            'TURRIS') mlr --csv --headerless-csv-output --skip-comments cut -f Address ;;
            'VIRIBACK_DOMAIN') mlr --csv --headerless-csv-output cut -f URL | get_domains_from_urls ;;
            'VIRIBACK_IPV4') mlr --csv --headerless-csv-output cut -f IP ;;
            'SHADOWSERVER_HOST') mlr --csv --headerless-csv-output cut -f http_host ;;
            'SHADOWSERVER_TARGET') mlr --csv --headerless-csv-output cut -f redirect_target ;;
            'WATCHLIST_INTERNET') mlr --csv --ifs ';' -N cut -f 1 ;;
            'CRUZ_IT') mlr --csv --headerless-csv-output clean-whitespace then cut -f ip_address ;;
            'PHISHTANK') mlr --csv --headerless-csv-output cut -f url | get_domains_from_urls ;;
            'BLOCKLIST_UA') mlr --csv --ifs ';' --headerless-csv-output cut -f IP ;;
            esac
            ;;
        'YAML')
            case "$LIST_FILTER" in
            'CRYPTOSCAMDB_BLACKLIST') yq '.[].name' ;;
            'CRYPTOSCAMDB_WHITELIST') yq '.[].url' | get_domains_from_urls ;;
            esac
            ;;
        esac | mawk 'NF && !seen[$0]++' |
        case "$LIST_FORMAT" in
        'DOMAIN')
            perl ./process_domains.pl 2>/dev/null
            ;;
        # https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Validate::IP
        'IPV4')
            case "$LIST_METHOD" in
            'BLOCK')
                perl -MData::Validate::IP=is_public_ipv4 -nE 'chomp; if(defined($_) && is_public_ipv4($_)) {say $_;}'
                ;;
            # Ensure bogons get whitelisted
            'ALLOW')
                perl -MData::Validate::IP=is_ipv4 -nE 'chomp; if(defined($_) && is_ipv4($_)) {say $_;}'
                ;;
            esac
            ;;
        'IPV6')
            case "$LIST_METHOD" in
            'BLOCK')
                perl -MData::Validate::IP=is_public_ipv6 -nE 'chomp; if(defined($_) && is_public_ipv6($_)) {say $_;}'
                ;;
            # Ensure bogons get whitelisted
            'ALLOW')
                perl -MData::Validate::IP=is_ipv6 -nE 'chomp; if(defined($_) && is_ipv6($_)) {say $_;}'
                ;;
            esac
            ;;
        'CIDR4')
            perl ./process_cidrs.pl 2>/dev/null
            ;;
        'CIDR6')
            perl ./process_cidrs.pl 2>/dev/null
            ;;
        esac
}

main() {
    jq -r --arg key "$(basename "$1")" --arg format "$3" 'to_entries[] |
        select(.key == $key) | .value |
        .content.filter as $content_filter |
        .content.type as $content_type |
        .formats[] |
        select(.format == $format) |
        "\($content_filter)#\($content_type)#\(.filter)"' lists.json |
        while IFS='#' read -r content_filter content_type list_filter; do
            process_list "$1" "$2" "$content_filter" "$content_type" "$list_filter" "$3"
        done
}

main "$1" "$2" "$3"
```

**`process_domains.pl`**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
use feature 'say';
use Try::Tiny;
use Text::Trim 'trim';
use Net::IDN::Encode 'domain_to_ascii';
use Data::Validate::Domain 'is_domain';

while (<>) {
  chomp;

  try {
    my $domain = domain_to_ascii(trim($_));

    if (defined($domain) && is_domain($domain, { domain_private_tld => { onion => 1 } })) {
      say($domain);
    }
  }
}
```

**`process_cidrs.pl`**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
use feature 'say';
use Try::Tiny;
use Text::Trim 'trim';
use Net::CIDR 'cidrvalidate';

while (<>) {
  chomp;

  try {
    # https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::CIDR#$ip=Net::CIDR::cidrvalidate($ip);
    my $cidr = cidrvalidate(trim($_));
    last if !defined $cidr;
    say $cidr;
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a major problem, but you really don't want to use CAPS for shell variable names. Since, [by convention](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/1081936), global environment variables are capitalized, it is bad practice to also use caps for your own, local variables because this can lead to naming collisions and hard to find bugs.

Comment: Previously discussed at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/284873/89257

Comment: @chicks Yes, but that's for a greater code review. Posting here is meant to focus more on command specifics and what not, as a code review more than likely isn't going to detail that information. The Linux specialists are here after all, and perhaps Mr. Tange himself will grace me with his presence!